# Blender running slow when editing rig, changing poses, and during animation

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, optimization

I've posted a similar question in the recent past, and have gotten some good advice, but it didn't solve the problem. Currently, I'm working on an anime-styled female character. I've completed the mesh for the body, the mesh for the clothes, and the hair. When I started rigging I had no issues with lagging or freezes when editing my rig.

Then it comes to the hair. When I started the bones for the hair I noticed Blender running slowly, but not anything serious. Now I can't edit the rig without having to wait several seconds between edits, changes in poses, and don't get me started on the .64 fps animation, even when the rig is standing still. I wanted to add physics to my hair so I added wiggle bones, but the lagging was occurring prior to adding the modifier. With the advice from earlier, I removed millions of unnecessary faces and triangles, mostly from prematurely applied subdivision modifiers.

Currently, my mesh has
41 Objects
504.667 vertices (down from 4 million)
1,003,840 Edges (down from 7-8 million)
499,302 Faces (down from 4 million)
1,002,692 Triangles (down from 7-8 million)

My PC isn't old or outdated (relatively mid/higher mid-tier):
Processor: Intel Core i9-10900F CPU 2.80GHz, 2808 Mhz, 10 Core(s),
GPU: AMD Radeon RX 5700 XT
Ram: 16GB

If anyone has a way to upload .blendfiles with instructions I'd be more than willing to upload the file! Thanks for the time to help me out!

PS this is my first project, so I'm not the most knowledgeable in all things Blender.
[image]

Comment: All I say is many people experience their PC slowing down when working with complex meshes and/or hair, although their machine isn't old or outdated. Especially hair is really not resource-friendly. And the misunderstanding many people make is that they expect the viewport to always run at the given FPS rate. This works well in simple scenes. But the FPS rate is mostly for playback of rendered files (Ctrl+F11), for setting the FPS creating movie files and for simulations to have a time relation. Anyway, if you want to upload a file, follow the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You might want to reduce subdivision modifiers and particles or instancing. The order of modifiers also affects performance. It is preferable to have the Armature as the last modifier in the stack. Your tri count still seems a bit excessive but shouldn't affect your computer this much. (also, please refrain from using comma or period as a thousands separator as it is not internationnal. use space if necessary)

Comment: When editing the modifiers, should the armature come before or after the subdivision surface modifier? And will do for next time! thanks for the help